# Calculating average relative humidity and wind velocity

Tags: geospatial, analysis, data

My goal is to have a single raster file containing the average relative humidity and wind velocity respectively of the last 11 years i.e. 2012-2022 for a certain region.

I have looked through and see that there are many posts on calculating average temperature however, am interested in relative humidity and wind velocity. I also came across WorldClim variables : https://www.worldclim.org/data/monthlywth.html, which has monthly mean of temperature and precipitation which I can use to get yearly temperature and precipitation mean.

Hence, I was wondering if someone could point me to a data source that contains information on relative humidity and wind velocity on google earth engine or elsewhere and also give me a high-level overview of how to calculate the average of the two variables.